# Как сделать повторяющийся текст в SVG?

Tags: html, svg

Я пытаюсь создать текст с надписью «Draft», который повторяется бесконечно. Он будет использоваться для заполнения страницы водяными знаками. (Я использую для этого SVG вместо фонового изображения, потому что мне нужно, чтобы оно также отображалось в режиме печати).

Куда бы я ни посмотрел, я вижу примеры SVG с повторяющимися фигурами. Например, это:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#64bee3" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="2" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```

Но когда я пытаюсь заменить фигуру в шаблоне на `<text>`, это не работает (в svg ничего не появляется).

Как создать текст, который повторяется бесконечно через определенные промежутки времени?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do I make a repeating text in an SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77326836/7394871) от участника  [@Primordial_Hamster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12257057/primordial-hamster).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/77326836/7394871

Comment: честно... по мне вопрос слишком простой для переводов в стиле "Q-A". На грани флага к закрытию "по опечатке".  Ответ на него дал только потому что полез проверять "да что тут может не получиться то?" и было уже просто жаль 3 раза нажатых контрол+ц, контрол+в.

Comment: @eri Для обучения самое то... Сколько более сложных и красивых ответов ушло с нулями... А тут вы уже 45 заработали. Да и не лукавьте, хотелось вам немного ... "А у меня получилось"

Comment: не, именно было интересно "что может не получиться тут у человека с 23 медальками?" искал подвох. расстроился когда не нашел.

Comment: @eri поэтому рука не поднимается поблагодарить человека, который вам помогает карму заработать :)

Comment: в начале рейтинг очень важен: мне приходилось удалять вопросы, чтоб задать новые, не хватало меток и пара тыщ нужна чтоб вопросы хоть кто-то читал из умных людей. после 2500 карма не особо важна. За рейтинг Спасибо, но плюсик этому вопросу не поставлю))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А у меня получилось. Возможно, Вы не указали размер или шрифт.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" x="10" y="10" width="250" height="70" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(20)">
  <style>
.small {
  font: italic 13px sans-serif;
}
.heavy {
  font: bold 30px sans-serif;
}

/* Note that the color of the text is set with the    *
 * fill property, the color property is for HTML only */
.Rrrrr {
  font: italic 40px serif;
  fill: red;
}
  </style>

  <text x="20" y="35" class="small">My</text>
  <text x="40" y="35" class="heavy">cat</text>
  <text x="55" y="55" class="small">is</text>
  <text x="65" y="55" class="Rrrrr">Grumpy!</text>            </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="2" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Нужны координаты начальной точки для текста в pattern. Попробуйте, в качестве дополнительной попытки, сделать текст наклонным. (+) С галочкой пока не буду торопиться, жду других ответов.

Comment: Вся линия текста под наклоном, а не отдельные буквы

Comment: Вся линия не проблема.)

Comment: Это был вопрос по ассоциации с Enso. Сразу не стал добавлять ссылку, так как люди хотят сами отвечать, готовые ответы не интересны, да и есть возможность заработать положительную карму

Comment: Если есть желание, то можно разместить свой ответ на EnSO

Comment: В этом ответе нет ничего нового по сравнению с имеющимся там. Не вижу смысла плодить одинаковые ответы

Comment: @Dev18 это вы к чему?

Answer (score 2):

Задайте по умолчанию координаты начала текста x,y и выравнивание текста [alignment-baseline="hanging"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline)

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="100" >
            <text x="50" y="0" font-family="Avenir" font-size="40" alignment-baseline="hanging">Draft</text>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```

***Второй вариант с заполнением паттерна текстом под углом.***

Для реализации наклона строки текста был добавлен `patternTransform="rotate(-35)"`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="600" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150" height="100" patternTransform="rotate(-35)" >
            <text x="70" y="0" font-family="Avenir" font-size="30" alignment-baseline="hanging">Draft</text>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   <rect width="100%" height="650" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77327122/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Comment: Привет, я хотел уточнить, а шрифт Avenir будет отображаться если он не подключен ?

Comment: @Monkey Mutant Привет, если он есть в твоей ОС, то конечно будет. Но лучше подключать, ведь на другом ПК его может не оказаться и он будет заменен на стандартный шрифи